# What is the rationale behind having [[nodiscard]] types?

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17, nodiscard

What are usecases in which it is beneficial to use a `[[nodiscard]]` type?

On types, `[[nodiscard]]` emits a warning if the return value of any function returning an instance of that type is omitted; (Citation from p0068r0):

> If [[nodiscard]] is marked on a type, it makes it so that all functions that return that type are implicitly
>   [[nodiscard]].

while a `[[nodiscard]]` constructor (c++2a) is very useful for classes which manage resources (e.g. `unique_ptr`) and nodiscard for functions are for instance useful for `make_unique` I cannot come up with an example where a nodiscard for a type is useful and I'm interested in cases where it is used.

Comment: Perhaps an error type?  That way any function returning the error type doesn't need to get marked up, and you can't forget to mark up the function(s) that return that type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the type `std::unique_lock<M>`. It's an obvious candidate for marking the constructor (specifically the one that takes `M&`) nodiscard, as we would not want to write some code like this by accident:

```
std::unique_lock<M>(m);
// oops! we actually meant
// std::unique_lock<M> lck(m);
```

This falls under the "manages resources" category.

But this is also an example of a type that we would not want to have discarded if returned from a function:

```
std::unique_lock<M> getLockFor(Arg x) {
    std::unique_lock<M> result;
    // acquire some lock based on x
    return result;
}

{
    auto lck = getLockFor(arg1);  // ok
    // do some stuff that requires the lock to be held
}
{
    getLockFor(arg2);  // warning!
    // lock will NOT be held here!
}
```

To get the warning in this case, we would need to mark the *type* as nodiscard, not just the constructor.

I think, in fact, this example illustrates that perhaps *most* classes that manage resources should be nodiscard, as it is probably a bug when we call a function that returns to us control over a resource, merely to release that resource immediately by not using the return value.